# Find comments associated with a specific function using regex

Tags: regex

I'm trying to use regex to extract the body of a comments block associated with a specific set of c++ functions. The comment format is well-known, as is the name of the functions. Comments start with `/**` and end with `*/`. My problem is that the start of comments for non-matching functions matches with the end of matching functions, and I can't figure out how to stop this from happening.

Here's the regex I'm using (python):

```
\/\*\*([\s\S]*)\*\/\s(\bfunc_sig\b)\s*\(([\s\S]*?)\)
```

and a block of test code:

```
/**
 *
 */


/**
 *
 */
func_sig()
```

I want to match only the bottom comment block and function, but the expression matches the whole thing. I've tried thinking of a way to exclude the `*/` from the middle of the search, which I think would solve the problem, but I can't figure out a good way to do it. I can exclude the `/` character from the bulk of the search entirely by changing the expression to

```
\/\*\*([^\/]*)\*\/\s(\bfunc_sig\b)\s*\(([\s\S]*?)\)
```

which works, but seems unnecessarily restrictive as there are valid reasons to use that character in a comment. Is there a good way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/l02NlX/1

Comment: `\/\*\*.*[\n\r]+(\s*\*.*[\r\n]+)*\s*\*\/\s*[\n\r]*\s*func_sig\(\)` just assumes that each line starts with in the middle of the comment starts with a `*`